# Flutter set available container width

Tags: flutter

I am using Navigation Rail in my app. So on-page, I am setting width with media query but the problem is it's not working fine in all devices on some device its show some extra white space in end. Is there any solution to show the remaining full `width` ? I also use `double.infinity` but its showing only a white screen.

Here is my code

```
class _PlaceListState extends State<PlaceList> {
  final List _places = [
    {'name': 'Hunza', 'where': 'Gilgit Baltistan'},
    {'name': 'Skardu', 'where': 'Gilgit Baltistan'},
    {'name': 'Murree', 'where': 'Gilgit Baltistan'},
    {'name': 'Murree', 'where': 'Gilgit Baltistan'},
    {'name': 'Murree', 'where': 'Gilgit Baltistan'},
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double statusBarHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top;
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.79,
      color: Color(0xffFFD438),
      child: new CustomScrollView(

        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        slivers: <Widget>[
          new SliverAppBar(

            backgroundColor: Color(0xffFFD438),
            expandedHeight: statusBarHeight * 5,

            flexibleSpace: new FlexibleSpaceBar(
              title: const Text('PLACES', textAlign: TextAlign.left, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color : Color(0xff292826)), ),

            ),
          ),
          new SliverPadding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2.0),
              sliver: new SliverFixedExtentList(
                itemExtent: 300.0,
                delegate: new SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                 (builder, index) => _buildListItem(index),
                 childCount: _places.length),
              )),

        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildListItem(int index) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            _places[index]['name'],
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color : Color(0xff292826)),
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: (){
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PlaceDetails()),
              );
            },
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                child: Card(
                  elevation: 40.0,
                  child: Container(
                    width: 200,
                    child: Image(
                        image:
                        AssetImage('assets/images/place.jpg')),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 7),
              child: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.55,
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(Icons.favorite_border, size: 20, color : Color(0xff292826),),
                    Spacer(),
                    Text(
                      _places[index]['where'],
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color : Color(0xff292826),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

As you see its showing white in end i am not sure why its happening because i use Mediaquery to set width and its working in some devices and in some its showing white in end

Comment: have you tried using Expanded()?

Answer (score -1):

Try to use only MediaQuery.of(context).size.width and delete 0.79, I hope it can help you

Comment: No its showing the yellow boundry error if i increasing the width

Comment: All numbers are different if we change device best solution I found is wrapped with Expanded widget